# Update version in package.json automatically while pushing branch in gitlab and running jenkins

Tags: angular, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab

My project is hosted in Gitlab and have a webhook hook which tells Jenkins to trigger a CI build when someone pushes code to the develop. What I looking for, whenever my branch merge in develop, should update the version automatically in package.json. Same thing when we run jenkins.

We are using gitlab-ci.yml in which we defined the gitlab pipeline steps and we have jenkinsfile in which we defined the pipeline steps for CI and pushing the data.

Let suppose, this is my current version:
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0.1",

What I want, it should automatically increment like:
"name": "test",
"version": "1.0.2",

Whenever we merge the branch in develop and same with jenkins.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is not a scripting service, but I will give to you a guide to do this

You just need a script that validates if your change is a major, minor or patch, change the package.json version and commit it to you

to help you, you can use the semver package https://www.npmjs.com/package/semver

just use it in your script and you will be able to do what you want

Comment: Thanks, is it possible that when we are merging the branch in git will update package.json automatically?